# Nuxt access layout property of matched component from middleware

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router, middleware

So I have this middleware which is in charge of loading content server side:

```
    try {
      const post = await import(`~/contents/help${route.path}${route.path.split('/').length == 2 ? '/index' : ''}.md`);
      store.commit('setHelpContent', post.default);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log('No Help available');
      store.commit('setHelpContent', null);
    }
```

But this only makes sense on some pages with a specific layout (the one that has a `<Help />` slot). Can I check on the matched component data on this?

I tried to inspect `route.matched[0].components`, without success :(

Another solution would be to being able to call `asyncData` on the layout component, but unfortunately this doesn't seem available :(

Thanks

Comment: You could just use the `middleware` property in the target layout component. Then it would just run for that layout.

Comment: That looks promising. I'll give it a try!